# Windows and Linux startup SSD

Tags: partitioning, windows, ssd

I want to install windows and linux on SSD as a booting drive.
Both systems will have separate disks for data.
I don't want to store private data on SSD.
How partition table should look like? Will it fit on 30-40GB drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how much Windows needs and we can't answer that here.

Ubuntu / can be as small as 10 Gb. If you add 5 Gb for a /home/ and do not create a different partition and do not use that /home/ but put the directories inside it onto the 2nd hard disk you will have more than enough with 15Gb.

From Ubuntu's view you can do

- /dev/sda1 mount as NTFS for C: Size will be size of disk -/- 15 Gb for ...
- /dev/sda2 mount as ext4 to / with 15 Gb
- /dev/sdb1 mount as NTFS to a directory you name with all of the Gb's that 2nd disk holds and you can mark this in Windows as D:

This also makes it so that you can share personal files between the 2 operating systems.  The remainder in the SSD can be used for Windows but you will have to check how much is needed.

I would go for a 120 Gb SSD though. The relative price seems to be better for this size and that size makes it certain you will have enough space (basically you could give Ubuntu 20 Gb for / with /home/ in it and have roughly 100Gb for Windows (that should be more than enough for all software you install).